# Coupon collector's problem with increasing number of coupons needed

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

In the ordinary coupon collector's problem, there are $n$ types of coupons, and we pick coupons uniformly at random until we get at least one of each coupon.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

It is well known that the expected time to collect all coupons $k$ times (for a *fixed* integer $k$) is $ n \log n + (k - 1) n \log\log n + O(n)$. But what if we need to collect all coupons $n$ times? Is the expected time $\omega(n^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Following [Balls into Bins: A tight analysis](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf) assume we throw $m$ balls independently and uniformly into $n$ bins and let $M$ be the maximum number of balls in any bin. This allows for $m$ to depend on $n$. Then, if $m\gg n (\log n)^3,$ the probability $P[M>k_\alpha]=o(1)$ if $\alpha>1$ and $P[M>k_\alpha]=1-o(1)$ if $\alpha\in (0,1).$ Here
$$
k_\alpha=\frac{m}{n}+
\sqrt{\frac{2 m \log n}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\log \log n}{2 \log n}\right)}.
$$
This means that there is threshold behaviour for the maximum load around $m/n,$ and it will be upper bounded by $k_\alpha$ with probability going to one if we take $\alpha>1.$ Now let $m=n^2,$ and note that the bounded maximum implies that at least $n^2$ time is needed for the minimum load to exceed $n.$ In other words, since the maximum load is very close to the average load so is the minimum load.

Comment: I don't understand this. Isn't it trivial that at least $n^2$ time is needed for the minimum load to exceed $n$? Why do you seem to conclude this from a sophisticated analysis? Also, the question asks whether the expected time is $\omega(n^2)$; you don't seem to say anything about that.